# How to add a loading image while UIWebView is loaded?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiwebview

In the main view of my app, I have a button that segue's to another view that has a `UIWebView`. Usually, it takes about 2-3 seconds to load.. During this awkward loading time, how can a loading image be added and animated?

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show/hide a HUD - like [`SVProgressHUD`](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD) or [`MBProgressHUD`](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) - withing the `UIWebViewDelegate` methods.

Set your controller as a delegate and implement, for instance, the two methods

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading..."];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
}
```